# cannot connect to network after today's updates in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager, internet

Good afternoon,
today I downloaded/installed the most recent updates for Ubuntu 16.04 
on my laptop (Lenovo B50-50), as I do regularly every day. I was asked to 
reboot the laptop. After the reboot I am not able to connect anymore. 
Network manager does not detect any wifi connection and also the cable 
connection does not work. network-manager is there and it is running. 
I restarted network-manager but nothing changes. Is there anyone who faced 
the same problem? Thanks

Comment: Probably the update was interrupted and linux-image-extra did not install.

Comment: A bad kernel also caused the same problem for me.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, there is no eth0, changes in the desktop etc.

Solution (temporary):

```
uname -r
-> 4.4.0-77-generic

ls /boot/initrd*
-> initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
-> initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic

reboot
```

When the grub screen appears, edit with `e`, replace the lines `4.4.0-77-generic` with `4.4.0-75-generic`, boot with F10.
Once it is running, purge the image with problems

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic
```

While it does not solve the problem you can continue to use the system until its solution.